# Блокировать посетителя при слишком частом обновлении страницы

Tags: php

На обычном хостинге как такое можно реализовать? Цель - разгрузить сайт. Допустим, если один человек делает более 5-10 переходов за короткий временной отрезок, то доступ к сайту на несколько минут блокируется.

Comment: а Вы это хотите прям на пхп делать или можно на nginx? тогда есть такое http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Comment: а вот, не выделенный сервер, а просто хостинг, сомневаюсь, что кто-то мне там что-то такое позволит сделать(

Comment: средствами самого пхп это можно сделать, но качество будет немного не то.  Но спросите своего хостера, может у него из коробки такое есть

Comment: хорошо, а если уж в пхп, то не подскажите всеж, в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: брать айпи пользователя, с базы по нему подымать статистику и смотреть, потом решать. Другое дело, что если с базы подымать все-все, то такой код уложит быстро Ваш сервер. Поэтому, я на самом деле бы хранил время последнего доступа и счетчик. При следующем запросе, если время меньше некого, увеличивал бы счетчик. Если счетчик достиг какого то лимита - приплыли. Если время больше какого то - обнуляем счетчик.  Да, айпи плохой айди пользователя, но для начала сойдет.

Comment: разгрузить то с какой точки зрения? мощностей не хватает,  или лимит запросов по тарифу?

Comment: 5-10 переходов это как-то несерьёзно вообще. Что-то я подозреваю, что вам лучше стоит или оптимизировать код своего сайта, или искать менее жадного хостера с более щадящими лимитами

Comment: @KoVadim проще в сессии хранить

Comment: тут на любителя. я просто давно-давно пхп трогал

Comment: @teran, да нет вроде проблем пока. я просто может шизю. новичок потом-что. на одной странице у меня просто происходит запрос на извлечение 50 последних записей, не более десяти полей на запись. эти записи часто  обновляются. ну и вот такая мыль пришла, может быть стоит как-то ограничить частоту такого запроса.

Comment: кэшируйте контент

Comment: если кешировать, то там можно же тоже будет условием проверять время как понимаю и делать новый запрос из бд а не из кеша в том случае если прошло достаточно количество времени, так приимрно, да?

Comment: или просто переписать запрос так, что бы он выполнялся более эффективно, всякие кеши, индексы.

Comment: нормально ли использовать кеширование в случае с часто меняющимися данными? Тоесть обновлять кеш раз в 5 минут если.

Comment: И еще у каждого юзера свои записи и свой отдельный кеш надо